# How to access and update variables defined outside, from screen class

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have defined a dictionary, and i will be accessing it with outer variables. 
I have defined 2 screens, and within these screens i will access these variables to put images.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition, SlideTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image

all_dicts = {1:'APPLE',2:'PINEAPPLE'}
start_list = 1
stri = all_dicts[start_list]

class Home(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SecSc(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.imgid.source = stri + ".png"
        if self.ids.txt1.text) == stri:
            self.parent.current = "3rd"
            # here i want to increment the start_list to + 1 to access next item in the Dictionary

class ThirdSc(Screen):
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.ids.imgid2.source = stri + ".png"
        if self.ids.txt1.text) == stri:
            self.parent.current = "4th"
            # here i want to increment the start_list to + 1 to access next item in the Dictionary

class Category(Screen):
    pass
```

Now i want the variable 'start_list' to be updated whenever the answer is right and use the updated variable for the next screen.

```
root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
Home:
    SecSc:
    ThirdSc:
    Category:
<SecSc>:
    name: '2nd'
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: imgid
            source:""
        TextInput:
            id: txt1
            text:""
<ThirdSc>:
    name: '3rd'
    FloatLayout:
        Image:
            id: imgid2
            source:""
        TextInput:
            id: txt2
            text:""
<Category>:
    name: 'category'
    BoxLayout:
''')
class MyiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget


MyiApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, 'start_list' is a global variable, if you want to change it you should just tell the compiler to use global 'start_list' instead of creating new local 'start_list'.

```
def on_enter(self, *args):
        global start_list
        self.ids.imgid.source = self.stri + ".png"
        if self.ids.txt1.text) == stri:
            self.parent.current = "3rd"
            start_list += 1
```

Comment: It throws up an error - local variable ‘start_list’ referenced before assignment.

Comment: Did you write 'global start_list' in both of your 'on_enter' methods?

Comment: Yes on both I added that.

Comment: Can you show me your new code and where is the error happening now?

Answer (score 0):

@Lothric,
My mistake, i had other methods which were accessing the variables. fixed now as suggested. I was trying to reduce the code to post the question here -

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random

Window.size = (1080, 1920)

all_dicts = {1:'APPLE',2:'PINEAPPLE'}
start_list = 1
stri = all_dicts[start_list]
normal_list = list(stri)
rand_list = list.copy(normal_list)
random.shuffle(rand_list)

class Home(ScreenManager):
    Pass

class FirstSc(Screen):
    def butloop(self):
        a = 'musicon.png'
        b = 'musicoff.png'
        c = self.ids.aa.source
        if c == a:
            self.ids.aa.source = b
        elif c == b:
            self.ids.aa.source = a
        return self.ids.aa.source
    def on_presStart(self):
        self.ids.ac.color = (.9,1,.9,1)
        self.ids.ac.size_hint = .497,.277
    def on_relStart(self):
        self.ids.ac.color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.ids.ac.size_hint = .5, .28


class ImBut(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class SecSc(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        global start_list
        global stri
        self.ids.imid.source = stri + ".png"
    def calc(self):
        global start_list
        global stri
        self.ids.buta.text = self.ids.txt1.text
        if self.ids.buta.text == stri:
            start_list += 1 # ITS WORKING NOW
            self.parent.current = "3rd"

class ThirdSc(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        global start_list
        global stri
        self.ids.imid2.source = stri + ".png"
    def calc(self):
        global start_list
        global stri
        self.ids.buta.text = self.ids.txt1.text
        if self.ids.buta.text == stri:
            start_list += 1 # ITS WORKING NOW
            self.parent.current = "2nd"
```

New problem is the next screen is not taking the updated variable, its still taking the first value only. I think all screens are loading at the start only.

```
root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition
Home:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    transition: SlideTransition()
    FirstSc:
    SecSc:
    ThirdSc:
    Category:
<ImButb@Button>
    id: imbutb
    font_size: 0.65 * self.height
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (0,0,0,0)
    back_color: (1,0,1,1)
    size_hint: (.15,.1)
    border_radius: [18]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.back_color
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
<FirstSc>:
    name: '1st'
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'bg.png'
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'firstframe.png'
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'firstframe_low.png'
        ImBut:
            id: aa
            pos_hint: {"x":.79,"top":.125}
            source: 'musicon.png'
            size_hint: .15,.08           
            on_release: root.butloop() 
        ImBut:
            id: ab
            pos_hint: {"x":.06,"top":.125}
            source: 'categ.png'
            size_hint: .15,.08           
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = 'category'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
        ImBut:
            id: ac
            text: ''
            pos_hint: {"x":.25,"top":.58}
            source: 'startplay.png'
            size_hint: .5,.28       
            on_press: 
                root.on_presStart()
            on_release:
                root.on_relStart() 
                app.root.current = '2nd'
<SecSc>:
    name: '2nd'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Image:
            id: imid
            source:""
        TextInput:
            id: txt1
            text:"aa"
            multiline: False
        Button:
            id: buttona
            on_press: root.calc()
        Label:
            id: buta

<ThirdSc>:
    name: '3rd'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Image:
            id: imid2
            source:""
        TextInput:
            id: txt2
            text:""
            multiline: False
        Button:
            id: buttonb    
        Label:
            id: butb

<Category>:
    name: 'category'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            font_size: 90
            text: 'categories'
            on_release: 
                app.root.current = '1st'
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
''')


class MyiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget


MyiApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I see. Yes, you are right, screens doesn't change dinamically by themselves, you have to make them do so. So, there's two solutions:

1. Call proper 'on_enter' method again after 'start_list' variable was changed. The thing is that source of your image is changing there:

```
self.ids.imid.source = stri + ".png"
```

2. Or you can define some new variable that equals 'stri' + '.png' as StringProperty() and after it was updated your screens will change:

```
stri = all_dicts[start_list]
srctrace = StringProperty()
srctrace = stri + '.png'
...
```

And in kv file:

```
       Image:
            id: imid
            source: srctrace
       ...
       Image:
            id: imid2
            source: srctrace
```

So, you'll need to update that variable also in 'calc' method or wherever 'start_list' is updated (I mean just write srctrace = stri + '.png' or create a method for that to call) but you won't need to update source of Image by id manually (like this: self.ids.imgid.source = self.stri + ".png")

Comment: Thank you. I think I solved it, I just added a new variable which equals “start_list” and important thing was to put that inside on_enter function. Now it updates correctly.